# Closing one element when opening another within the same loop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list, loops

first time on here so i'll try my best to explain what I'm asking.

So I have 3 list items with the same class name. I've put them in a looping function so that when you click on one it will display a sub set of list items for that specific list item. I also have them inside an if statement that adds a new class name to the specific list item that was clicked. It allows opening and closing of the sub list items when you click the corresponding parent element.

My question is; how can I use this same principle of checking for the additional class name, when the user clicks any of the list items. In other words, I am trying to code it in a way that will allow me to close any of the open sub list items when the user clicks a new list item.

This is what I came up with but it doesn't know what button[i] is when I include it within the "click" function. What I was trying to do with this code is to take whatever list item was clicked, and then check the previous and next iterations of the class name "button" to see if any of the contain also contain the class name "clicked.

HTML

```
  <div class="main">
    <ul>                
      <li><a href="#" class="button">One</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">One-1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">One-2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
       <li><a href="#" class="button">Two</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Two-1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Two-2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
           <li><a href="#" class="button">Three</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Three-1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Three-2</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.main ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.main ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");

for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {

    button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

        var prevItem = button[i - 1];
        var nextItem = button[i + 1];

        if (prevItem.className !== "button") {
            prevItem.className = "button";
            prevItem.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
        }

        if (nextItem.className !== "button") {
            nextItem.className = "button";
            nextItem.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
        }

        if (this.className === "button") {
            this.className += " clicked";
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

I am wanting to make this code usable no matter how many list items you add. So checking exactly button[0] button[1] and button[2] wasn't really an option, but I can see how button[i + 1] might not check every list item after it but rather just the next one. I tried adding another loop but ran into similar issues. anyway that's why I'm here. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You could use another loop and just loop through 0 to `button.length`. Check every index except for when `outer loop index == inner loop index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, I quickly rephrase it in my own words.

Question: "I have an arbitrary number of list elements, of which each contains a button and a nested list. The button is always visible, the nested list is hidden by default. When the user clicks on a button, the corresponding nested list should be shown. At the same time, all other shown nested lists should be hidden again. How can I achieve this?"

The original HTML looks fine:

```
<div class="main">
  <ul>                
    <li><a href="#" class="button">One</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Two</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Two-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="button">Three</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Three-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three-2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS I did not fully understand, but I suggest the following:

```
.main ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.main li.is-active ul {
  display: block;
}

.main ul ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

By adding the "is-active" class to an LI element, it is shown. This way, the CSS controls the visibility.

For the JavaScript part, I suggest this:

```
const buttonElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.button'));
buttonElements.forEach(buttonElement => {
  buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    const activeElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.is-active'));
    activeElements.forEach(activeElement => {
      activeElement.classList.remove('is-active');
    });
    buttonElement.parentElement.classList.add('is-active');
  });
});
```

This solution assumes you can use newer versions of JavaScript/ECMAScript. Overall, it makes use of const and arrow functions.

First, we get all elements with the class "button" by using [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Since the result is a NodeList and no array, we convert it using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Afterwards, we loop through the array by using [Array.prototpye.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). We add an event listener for the "click" event. When a button is clicked, we search for all elements with the "is-active" class and for each one remove it. Finally, we add the "is-active" class to the parent element of the clicked button using [Node.prototype.parentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

Here is another solution that works in older browsers:

```
var buttonElements = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttonElements.length; i++) {
  buttonElements[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
    var activeListElements = document.getElementsByClassName('is-active');
    for (var i = 0; i < activeListElements.length; i++) {
      activeListElements[i].setAttribute('class', '');
    }
    event.target.parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'is-active');
  });
}
```

This is pretty much the same as the other approach but works with older versions of JavaScript.

Generally, the idea is to focus on an arbitrary sum of elements instead of an array with a specific length. In natural language something like: "Give me all buttons. For every button, add an event listener. When a button is clicked, give me all active list elements and remove their active status. Then, mark the list item above the button as active".

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, wow thank you! I wasn't expecting such a detailed reply. This is what i was trying to achieve but could think how to get there. Thanks again :)